# AngularJS: run function on view update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm playing around with AngularJS (and trying to get my head round it) and have a controller which for the purpose of this question can be simplified to:

```
$scope.addMessage = function() {
      $scope.messages.push({author: 'nick', 
        text: $scope.messageText, active: true});
};
```

Every time that the model changes due to this '$scope.addMessage' I want to run `emojify.run();`... If I simply put it after `$scope.messages.push...` it runs before the data is shown in the view and therefore doesn't work. How do I call the function `emojify.run();` once the view has updated?

Comment: I suspect that there is a better way to do what you are attempting.  AngularJS to my knowledge [does not support this type of pattern](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1306).  Are you trying to change something in the DOM after the data updates?  If so, look into [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  Having your controller manipulate the DOM directly seems to violate the MVC principles that AngularJS is meant to be used with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the scope.$watch listener on your model

See this tutorial that does something similar: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs

$watch is called in the $digest phase. For details see the Scope lifecycle here:  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope